How to get full item property from dropdown formControl valueChanges?
What i want is some guidance/suggestion on usage of the formControl.valueChanges.
When an item is selected from a drop-down box, i want to be able to access the full item of the selected item, and not just the itemID, when using the valueChanges
my current scenario are like so:
// component.ts
interface SomeItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

someIDFormControl = new FormControl(0)
someData$: Observable<SomeItem[]> = this._someService.getAll()

selectedItem$ = this.someIDFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  map(itemID => {
    // how can i get the full item property from here
  })
)

<select [formControl]="someIDFormControl">
  <option *ngFor="let item of (someData$|async)" [value]="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>

with following requirements:

must use FormControl.valueChanges because I intend to use the {emitEvent: false} with patchValue/setValue


Simply based on what I currently know, the only idea i got is to pipe the someData$ with shareReplay(), then combine with switchMap\map pipe. But this would require additionally find again from the array which doesn't seems ideal(?).
example:
someData$: Observable<SomeItem[]> = this._someService.getAll().pipe(shareReplay(1))
selectedItem$ = this.someIDFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  switchMap(id => {
    return this.someData$.pipe(map(itemArr => itemArr.find(item => item.id === id)))
  })
)


Instead of [value] you can use [ngValue], that will give whole object in valueChanges.
[value] gives you output in string format whereas [ngValue] gives output in object format

HTML

<select [formControl]="someIDFormControl">
  <option *ngFor="let item of options" [ngValue]="item">
    {{ item.name }}
  </option>


TS

interface SomeItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
export class AppComponent {
  options = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'abc',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'xyz',
    },
  ];

  someIDFormControl = new FormControl<SomeItem | null>(null);

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.someIDFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz link here

You can use RXJS operator withLatestFrom, to store the previously selected item to reduce redundant lookups.
For more about withLatestFrom please check this answer
selectedItem$ = this.someIDFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.someData$),
  scan((prevSelected, [itemID, items]) => {
    if (prevSelected?.id === itemID) {
      return prevSelected; // No need to search again
    }
    return items.find(item => item.id === itemID);
  }, null)
);

